# PostgreSQL Foreign Key with a condition

Tags: postgresql

Using postgres sql,  is there a way to set up a condition on foreign key where it's limited to to another table like a normal foreign key constraint, but also allows the value of 0 to exist without it being in the other table. For example:

```
table_a:
  id

table_b:
  id
  foreign_key_on_table_a_id
```

table_a would have a list of things, and table_b relates to table_a, but has the foreign key constraint. I would also like it to allow for a value of 0 even though there is no id of 0 in table_a.

Is this the right constraint to use? Is there another/better way of doing this without adding the value into table_a?

Comment: Why not allow NULLs in the referencing column and use NULL instead of zero? Sentinel values are generally a bad idea.

Comment: Normally I would agree with you, but I'm working with a company that requires foreign key constraints like what is mentioned above. Believe me, if I had it my way, there would be an overhaul of what they do.

Comment: Umm, you can put a NULL in a column that is FKed to another table's PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change `foreign_key_on_table_a_id` to allow NULL values. Then use an FK as usual and put NULLs in there instead of zero. You can have a NULL in a column that references another table.

Alternatively, you could write a function that returns true if a value is in the other table and false otherwise and then add a CHECK constraint:

```
CHECK (your_column = 0 or the_function(your_column))
```

You won't get any of the usual cascade behavior for FKs though and this CHECK is a massive kludge.

Comment: Well I feel like a silly goose right now. The database was set up that way properly. The problem was with my code. I should've been setting things to NULL instead of to a value that doesn't exist. Thank you for pointing me in the place I needed to look.

Comment: @Jason: Sounds like the "talking to the wall" debugging technique :) It can be hard to see something that's right in front of you. On the upside, you don't have to resort to the awful CHECK kludge.